# Vertically align a heading and a paragraph in a div

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to vertically align a h1 element and p in the middle of a div floated left but they end up next to each other vertically aligned. Im pretty sure it to do with the table-cell display but don't know how to vertically align without it.

my code gives me:

```
.
.
Heading Paragraph
.
.
```

I want:

```
.
.
Heading
Paragraph
.
.
```

heres my code:

CSS:

```
#HDRtext 
{
    float:  left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 335px;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    color:  white;
}

#HDRtext h1 
{
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 2em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#HDRtext p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size:1em;
    font-family: Georgia;
}
```

Here are the jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8cw2/)

Comment: Look at this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div), and this useful resources: [link](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [vertically align the div](http://www.vertical-align.com/) that contains them (or place them inside another div and place that in original div).

Comment: Thanks Kyomu i place it in another div and vertically aligned it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a page with an exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/Z468Z/1/

I changed your id by a class, using ID in css is a bad habit.

I personaly prefer inline-block as table/table-row/table-cell display.

What you have to know to vertical-align middle with inline-block :

- the container must have height and line-height at the same size.
- the child you want at the middle, must be the type "inline-block", in this child you must restore proper line-height
- his children can be block types ( as in my example )

Comment: Thanks DieVarDump, i like this as it not using table-cell display

Answer (score 0):

[This Page](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html) Explains and shows a method of vertical alignment towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

To properly vertical center elements, you need to have an absolute positioned div that is 50% of the height from the top, and then an offset div with a margin-top of -50% total height of the div. A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jefffabiny/xXZfb/1/